# DAX - Filter between two specified dates

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

1. Table 1 (Combined Hours) I have a list of [payweek], which is many repeated
   [image: Image of Combined Table]
2. Table 2 (All Scripts), I have a list of jobs and two dates, [Scripting Date] and [R4PreScriptDate]
   [image: Image if All Scripts table]
3. I am trying to find the number of unique [payweek]s between the [Scripting Date] and the [R4PreScriptDate]
4. The DAX formula is below. My result is always 3. However, I am expecting variable answers (0,1, 2,3,4 or 5)

   ```
   R4PreScriptWkCt = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(CombinedHours[payWeek]),FILTER(CombinedHours, 
   CombinedHours[payWeek] <= MAX (AllScripts[Scripting Date] )
   && CombinedHours[payWeek] >= MAX (AllScripts[R4PreScriptDate] ) ))
   ```

Thank you,

Comment: If you can provide some example data and expected result it would be much more easy to help you.

Comment: thank you for the feedback.I added the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that both tables are related by Job Number. I created the following measure:

```
R4PreScriptWkCt =
VAR __date2 = MAX ( AllScripts[R4PreScriptDate] )
VAR __date1 = MAX ( AllScripts[Scripting Date] )
VAR __job = MAX ( AllScripts[Job Number] )
VAR __subTable =
    FILTER (
        CombinedHours,
        CombinedHours[Job Number] = __job
            && CombinedHours[Week] >= __date1
            && CombinedHours[Week] <= __date2
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK ( CombinedHours[Week] ), __subTable )
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I didn't think to approach it that way. Now, I am getting blanks instead of 3. However, I think you are on the right track. I am probably using the measure incorrectly. Does the [Week] need to be added to the subtable or is it already included? Sorry, this is WAAAYYY different from excel. Thanks for help